# How to write a script/formula for Google Form Responses to send submitted form to different emails based on a response?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a registration form that we are using for my company. We have 6 locations. I want to have the registration form that is filled out on Google forms to go to specific emails based on their answer for what location they are at. I have tried a few scripts, and have had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd write an if then statement that covers your 6 locations. It'd be something like this . . . though this isn't exact.

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var lastRow = getLastRow();
  var range = sheet.getRange('C'. lastRow);//location cell
  var location = range.getValue();
  if (location === 'heaven'){
     emailAddress = 'heaven@location.com'
     } 
    elseif (location === 'hell'){
     emailAddress = 'hades@location.com'
   } elseif (location === 'purgatory') {
     emailAddress = 'purg@location.com' 
   }else { 
     emailAddress ='void@location.com'
   }


MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: emailAddress,
     subject: subject,
     htmlBody: message     
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you expect that the individuals to whom the email is to be sent for each location might change occasionally, you might consider creating another sheet with a table which can be modified without touching the script:

> | Location 1 | john.doe@email.com |
>
> | Location 2 | jane.smith@email.com |

Then you could use something like this to pull values from the table (forgive my naming conventions):

```
  var location = range.getValue();

  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName('NameOfSheetWithTable');
  var range2 = sheet2.getRange(1, 1, 2, 2); // adjust to your table's range
  var data2 = range.getValues();
    for (var i=0; i < data2.length; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j < data2[i].length; j++) {
      var location1 = data2[0][0];
      var location2 = data2[1][0];
      var email1 = data2[0][1];
      var email2 = data2[1][1];
      }
      } 
  if (location == location1) {emailAddress = email1;}
  else if (location == location2) {emailAddress = email2;}
  // etc etc
```